# Help with webview - android

Tags: android, webview

I'm having troubles with a mini app which I am working on.

The mini app has a button and a webview.

The function of the button is to call a random url from a 30 url's list and to show the selected url in the webview. If you press the button again, it shows another url from the list.

Initially it was working fine, but sometimes, apparently without a reason, the web loads, but doesn't show its content.

I know it actually loads becouse I see at my log "onPageFinished()", the load ends but it only shows a blank screen. I have to reboot the app to make it work again.

I tried adding a "webView.clearCache(true)" after the load, but it doesn't work neither.

I also tried to make the button calls a "webView.loadUrl("about:blank")" in first place, but dosn't help. Even tried with "clearView()"

Sometimes it takes a while to fail, other times it seems to happen on a few trys.

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Kind regards

...Nothing in Logcat, everything looks good

Comment: Is there anything in logcat? and did you turn on JavaScript if needed?

Comment: did you found a solution for this problem? I'm running a 4.0.3 tablet and I'm having the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Can you see which pages are failing? If you comment out the random mechanism and set the WebView to display one of the failing pages does it show? If not it is likely that the content you are trying to display can't be handled by your webview. You might need to enable flash plugins, or JavaScript on your WebView. Without knowing what the pages contain though I can only guess.

Comment: I know It's late, but I'm having the same issue Pedro did (or so it seems). Point is: The content of the page is always the same, it just doesn't display sometimes...